# How to use PubNub with BackgroundTimer in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, pubnub

I´m trying to implement PubNub in a React Native application. The idea is to run PubNub in the background so that every 30s the location of the user is updated in a specific channel.

Here's my code. It's the export default function inside my App.js:

```
export default function ponte() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(false);
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState(null);
  const [volunteerChannel, setVolunteerChannel] = React.useState(null);

  // Handle user state changes
  function onAuthStateChanged(user) {
    setUser(user);
    if (isLoading) setIsLoading(false);
  }

  if (isLoading) return null;

  useEffect(() => {
    SplashScreen.hide();
    const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);
    return subscriber; // unsubscribe on unmount
  }, []);

  const authContext = React.useMemo(() => {
    return {
      signIn: (email, password) =>
        auth()
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.email, password.password)
          .then(res => {
            setIsLoading(false);
            setUser(res.user.uid);
      })
    ,
      signUp: () => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        setUser("test");
      },
      signOut: () => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        auth().signOut().then(() => console.log('User signed out!'));
        setUser(null);
      }
    };
  }, []);
  
  BackgroundTimer.start();
  BackgroundTimer.runBackgroundTimer(() => {

    if(auth().currentUser && auth().currentUser.email /*&& !volunteerChannel*/) {
        Promise.all([
          fetch(API_URL + "/users?email=" + auth().currentUser.email)
      ])
      .then(([res1]) => Promise.all([res1.json()]))
        .then(([data1]) => { 
          if(data1[0].category === 'Voluntario') {
            console.log('Volunteer channel: ' + data1[0].email);

            GetLocation.getCurrentPosition({
              enableHighAccuracy: true,
              timeout: 15000,
            })
            .then(location => {
                var pubnub = new PubNubReact({
                  publishKey: 'xxxx',
                  subscribeKey: 'xxxx'
                });
                pubnub.publish({
                  message: {
                    latitude: location.latitude,
                    longitude: location.longitude
                  },
                  channel: data1[0].email
                });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                const { code, message } = error;
                console.warn(code, message);
            })
          } else {
            console.log(data1[0]);
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error))
    } 
  }, 30000);

  BackgroundTimer.stop();

  return(
    <AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <RootStackScreen user={user} />
      </NavigationContainer>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );

}
```

I'm worried about two things with this code:

- The first one is the amount of pubnub transactions registered: Apparently I have over 3.5K transactions and I barely used the app in the iOS simulator.
- The second is I get a warning: `CANCELLED Location cancelled by another request`. I'm not so sure where that comes from, maybe it comes from GetLocation.getCurrentPosition so it might not be related to PubNub.

So my question is: Am I using the right approach to use PubNub in React Native? If not, what can I do to make it better?

Comment: When you say "background" do you mean a background thread while the app is active or do you mean background as in the app is not active on the device? If the former, then you just need to be sure that the pubnub instance is still in scope as well as the listener. If you mean iOS background app, then you must have permission to do so both by Apple (approval) and by user.

Comment: CANCELLED Location cancelled by another request sounds like a custom message by your app but if it could also just be that when the app goes into background (or the thread is not able to run in the background of your active app) that it is losing connection to PubNub (not PubNub's fault, btw). And that is just the app telling you that's what happened. If you change the list of channels you are subscribed to, that could also cause that message because the subscribe connection has to be reestablished and the old connection is dropped in favor of the new connection.

Comment: @CraigConover I would be OK with it running like a background thread while the app is active, that is what I was trying to do here. Is my approach ok? If not, is there any link that might serve me as an example?

Comment: Have you tried running pubnub instance/addListener/subscribe NOT in a background thread. It should just work. JS is async.

Comment: @CraigConover so directly inside my export default function Ponte without the background timer? Ok I'll try that. Sorry for my poor knowledge.

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/react-native-pubnub-real-time-location-tracking/ I was actually trying to follow that tutorial but since I wanted to start sending my location right when the app was started I didn't know how to put PubNub inside my functional component of the App.js

Comment: So if you follow the code in that tutorial, does it work? I don't see any use of Background in that app and there shouldn't be a need to do so.

Comment: @CraigConover But the app in the tutorial is meant to send the user's location while he is on one specific screen. In this case I need to send the user´s location constantly when the app is in use.

Comment: So you can modify the frequency of the publishes by only calling it every 30s. Right?

Comment: mm ok, how can I do that?

Comment: Just clone that app and only publish the GPS position data every 30s.